# Using Shared Prefrences to store Username string in AlertDialog Builder

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I'm using below code on `Mainactivity` to store Username as a string in `AlertDialog`.

But, I would like to store the username using `SharedPreferences` or any method ( if there is any ) and when User opens app then initially stored username will be Displayed first.

```
  private void request_user_name() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Enter name:");

        final EditText input_field = new EditText(this);
        String e  = input_field.getText().toString();

        builder.setView(input_field);
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {


                  name = input_field.getText().toString();
            }
        });

        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                dialogInterface.cancel();
                request_user_name();
            }
        });

        builder.show();
    }
```

I used Shared Prefrences like below but it didn't work

```
  private void request_user_name() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Enter name:");

        final EditText input_field = new EditText(this);
        String e  = input_field.getText().toString();
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(username, e);
        editor.commit();
        builder.setView(input_field);
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {


                  name = input_field.getText().toString();
            }
        });

        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                dialogInterface.cancel();
                request_user_name();
            }
        });

        builder.show();
    }
```

Here is the image when app is first initialized

[image]

My whole Mainactivity file is

```html
package com.nepalpolice.mnemonics.chat;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.nepalpolice.mnemonics.R;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button  add_room;
    private EditText room_name;
    EditText edittext;
    private Toolbar mainToolbar;
    public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs" ;
    public static final String username = "userKey";
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    private ListView listView;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
    private ArrayList<String> list_of_rooms = new ArrayList<>();
    private String name;
    private DatabaseReference root = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().getRoot();
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);

        mainToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.main_chatbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mainToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Chat Rooms");

        progressBar= (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.webViewProgressfaq);


        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);


        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list_of_rooms);

        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);


        if(isNetworkStatusAvialable (getApplicationContext())) {
            request_user_name();
            root.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
                    Iterator i = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();

                    while (i.hasNext()) {
                        set.add(((DataSnapshot) i.next()).getKey());
                    }

                    list_of_rooms.clear();
                    list_of_rooms.addAll(set);

                    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You're Offline!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }



            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Chat_Room.class);
                    intent.putExtra("room_name",((TextView)view).getText().toString() );
                    intent.putExtra("user_name",name);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }





    private void request_user_name() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Enter name:");

        final EditText input_field = new EditText(this);
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.setView(input_field);
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                  name = input_field.getText().toString();
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
                editor.putString("username", name);
                editor.commit();
            }
        });

        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                dialogInterface.cancel();
                request_user_name();
            }
        });

        builder.show();
    }

    public static boolean isNetworkStatusAvialable (Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager cm =
                (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetwork != null &&
                activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();

    }
}
```

Comment: Your saving an empty string because they haven't entered their name yet. Simply put: `editor.putString("username", name );  editor.commit();` inside the `onClick` of the `OK`

Comment: @Derek, Thanks for your suggestion but I did as you suggested but still when I close app and reopen still it popups the Dialog Box with Empty EditTextview......what am I doing wrong. I have included my whole Mainactivity...Hope it'll help you to understand my problem more better.

Comment: Check my edit on my answer

Comment: @Derek, yes it worked.......not one last question how to put the cursor at the end of string....as for now the cursor appears at front of string so if userhas to input new name they need to first put cursor at end and then delete which is bit annyoing...can it be done?

Comment: It can be done using `setSelection`. Like so: `input_field.setselection(input_field.getText().length());`

Comment: But it throws error in setselection when I put above code inside private void request_user_name() {.?

Comment: Ok I got it ..I need to put second S as Capital. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Let me know if my answer worked.

Comment: @Derek yes derek it worked except that cursor at the end.

Comment: I will change my answer to reflect the cursor

Comment: If my answer solved your problem the best, please consider marking it as correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not saving username on OK button click and to show saved username set text if you have saved data available.

Replace your function with below, you will see your expected result.

```
private void request_user_name() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Enter name:");

        final EditText input_field = new EditText(this);
        //String e  = input_field.getText().toString();
        final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();       
        builder.setView(input_field);
        String savedName = sharedpreferences.getString(username,"");
        input_field.setText(savedName);
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                  String name = input_field.getText().toString();
                  editor.putString(username, name);
                  editor.apply();
            }
        });

        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                dialogInterface.cancel();
                request_user_name();
            }
        });

        builder.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
editor.putString(username, e);
editor.commit();
builder.setView(input_field);
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {


                name = input_field.getText().toString();
        }
    });
```

To:

```
builder.setView(input_field);
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                name = input_field.getText().toString();

                editor.putString("username", name);
                editor.commit();
        }
    });
```

You are trying to save the username before the user entered anything and pressed "OK"

**Edit:**

To set the value at the beginning:

When you create the `EditText` set the value of the username, otherwise if `username` doesn't exist it will set to a blank string

```
final EditText input_field = new EditText(this);
input_field.setText(sharedpreferences.getString("username",""));
```

To force the cursor at the end of the `EditText` add:

```
input_field.setSelection(input_field.getText().length());
```